# Is it possible to seek through streamed youtube audio with discord.py (play from a given timestamp in the video)?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

Unfortunately passing in a URL with a &t= tag does not cause `discord.py`'s `VoiceClient` to start playing at that timestamp. I'm using `youtube_dl`.

Is is possible to seek through audio within discord.py in order to start streaming a YouTube video from somewhere besides the start?

I know some professional bots like [Groovy](https://groovy.bot/) have seek commands for streamed YouTube videos, so the Discord API itself is capable of this.

The code I'm using is from [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ffmpeg_options`, you're able to seek to a specific timestamp with the use of the `-ss` flag.

This is just how the options should look if you wish to start from, for example, 40 seconds:

```py
ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn -ss 40'
}
```

And of course you can add an optional variable to the `stream` command:

```py
import typing # for the optional argument of the timestamp

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False, timestamp=0):
        # moved the options from outside the class to inside the method.
        # this allows the use of variables in the options
        ffmpeg_options = {
            'options': f'-vn -ss {timestamp}'
        }
        # rest of the from_url code

    @commands.command()
    async def stream(self, ctx, timestamp: typing.Optional[int]=0, *, url): # add the arg
        """Streams from a url (same as yt, but doesn't predownload)"""

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True, timestamp=timestamp)
            # other code
```

I only added in the code that I edited from the music bot example, so I hope it's clear what I edited. If any further clarification is needed/how something works, then I'll be happy to make edits.

---

**References:**

- [FFMPEG Docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) - Ctrl + F for `-ss`.
- [Optional arguments in discord commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-optional)
- [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6.0+

Comment: I was wondering where your code snippet is originating from (not mentioned in refs) as it uses **YTDLSource**. So I googled and think it's related to [YouTube.py](https://gist.github.com/jffz/82a3b41afc48e3f6fcd958684880f60c), right!?

In the repository of [Discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) I could only find some similar but simpler looking class [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/1952060e1af7224ed7b67bc957e47247f6b50493/examples/basic_voice.py).

Comment: Hey @e.d.n.a, I'm just using the [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) that was given in the question! I just took out some bloating in the code and showed the parts that would need editing in my answer.