# Seeking with ffmpeg options fails or causes delayed playback in Discord bot

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl, pycord

My Discord bot allows users to play a song starting from a timestamp.

The problem is that playback is delayed and audio plays faster and is jumbled if start times >= 30s are set.

Results from testing different start times. Same URL, 30 second duration:

| Entered Start Time (s) | Playback Delay (s) | Song Playback Time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 30 |
| 30 | 10 | 22 |
| 60 | 17 | 17 |
| 120 | 31 | 2 |
| 150 | 120 | <1 |

I am setting the start time using ffmpeg_options [as suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354887/is-it-possible-to-seek-through-streamed-youtube-audio-with-discord-py-play-from).

Does anyone understand why the audio playback is being delayed/jumbled? How can I improve playback delay and allow users to start in the middle of a multi-chapter YouTube video?

Code:

```
import discord
import youtube_dl
import asyncio


# Suppress noise about console usage from errors
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ""


ytdl_format_options = {
    "format": "bestaudio/best",
    "outtmpl": "%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s",
    "restrictfilenames": True,
    "noplaylist": False,
    "yesplaylist": True,
    "nocheckcertificate": True,
    "ignoreerrors": False,
    "logtostderr": False,
    "quiet": True,
    "no_warnings": True,
    "default_search": "auto",
    "source_address": "0.0.0.0",  # Bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues at certain times
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source: discord.AudioSource, *, data: dict, volume: float = 0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get("title")
        self.url = data.get("url")

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False, timestamp = 0):
        ffmpeg_options = {
            "options": f"-vn -ss {timestamp}"}

        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        if "entries" in data:
            # Takes the first item from a playlist
            data = data["entries"][0]

        filename = data["url"] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)

@bot.slash_command()
async def play(ctx, audio: discord.Option(), seconds: discord.Option(), timestamp: discord.Option()):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(audio, loop=bot.loop, stream=True, timestamp=int(timestamp))
    voice.play(player)
    await asyncio.sleep(int(seconds))
    await voice.disconnect()

token = token value
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Your question is about a specific problem with playback, I doubt you need this many lines of code to repro it.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Removed extraneous code. Do you have any feedback to offer about the problem?